# How to get hostPort mapped inside Docker Container in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

While deploying a Docker container inside AWS ECS, I have a `hostPort` mapped with value `0` so that it can avoid host port conflict and pick any available ephemeral port.

I have a need to get this actual value of `hostPort` it mapped to inside the Docker container (e.x. I am using an application which has embedded hazelcast and I need to set the public address with something like this  ). I can get that from outside the container by running `docker info` on that container but not inside the container.

Some of other popular systems like mesos/marathon provides environment variable like `PORT_8080` or `PORT_5701` or `PORT0`, `PORT1`, but nothing like this in AWS ECS service.

Is there any way even hacky to get this bounded `hostPort` from inside Docker. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions AWS experts here ??? or do I need to tag with some other specific to get attention. I am stuck to get it moving any recommendation would be great help. I am surprised even AWS ECS doesn't have anything to provide this information which is a very common feature in all the docker container orchestrator these days.